# Grafana version differs on docker container and web display

Tags: docker, grafana

I installed a container today using this part of my docker-compose :

```
grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: grafana
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    networks:
        - monitoring
    volumes:
        - ./volumes/grafana:/var/lib/grafana
    user: "472"
```

When I move inside the docker container, the `apk list | grep grafana` command renders the following packages :

```
grafana-openrc-7.3.6-r0 x86_64 {grafana} (Apache-2.0)
grafana-7.3.6-r0 x86_64 {grafana} (Apache-2.0)
```

However, when I start Grafana in my web browser (localhost:3000), I find that the version is

```
Grafana v8.0.3 (cae5c5e46b)
```

How is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/main/Dockerfile) of grafana, you could see it just use the source code in repo to build grafana docker image:

```
COPY tsconfig.json .eslintrc .editorconfig .browserslistrc .prettierrc.js ./
COPY public public
...
```

You could see it never use `apk add grafana` to build out `grafana/grafana`. So even the apk package in the alpine is `7.3.6`, the docker image did not use it, it usee the latest `8.0.3` which from source.